# SQL Query different value from same column

Tags: sql, join

Was required to query data from tables `PRODUCTS` and `CUSTOMERS`. The expected results are like below:

> CUST_NAME(from) | PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_DESC | ETA | CUST_NAME(to)

The `CUST_NAME(from)` and `CUST_NAME(to)` are both from the same table (`CUSTOMERS`). How do I query my SQL statement like that to query 2 different value from the column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join `CUSTOMER` twice on table `PRODUCTS` because there are two columns that are dependent on it,

```
SELECT  b.Name as CustNameFrom,
        a.Product_Name,
        a.Product_Desc,
        a.ETA,
        c.Name as CustNameTo
FROM    Products a
        INNER JOIN Customer b
            ON a.cust_from = b.ID
        INNER JOIN Customer c
            ON a.cust_to = c.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7b5a/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)